# Any hook in WordPress that runs after session is started?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to set a session value in my plugin, but session isn't started when WordPress loads my plugin and I don't want to run `if (!session_id()) session_start();` manually, because other plugins might rely on setting cookies, etc and face a "headers already sent error".

Is there any hook in WordPress that runs after session is started?

If not, how do you professionals handle such situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress does not use session. There are actually a number of reasons for this outlined very well in this stackexchange post:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167585/using-sessions-to-filter-posts-bad-thing/168089#168089

I would say if you are concerned about stepping on a plugin's toes, try hooking into "plugins_loaded" and use that hook as an entry for your plugin (if you can, I know that will limit functionality somewhat). But because Wordpress does not start a session itself it is really a coin toss whether you are interrupting another plugin or not.

Comment: I had know idea it's possible to securely authenticate users without sessions, thank you very much for the info.

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` isn't used by Wordpress.

Have you tried `wp_loaded` firing after WordPress is fully loaded? Or even `wp` which fire after the WP object is set up (ref array).

You can have a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hooks-actions-run-sequence) which will give you the action run sequence.

You can also have a look at the CODEX to have a better view at all action hooks available https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: I had know idea it's possible to securely authenticate users without sessions, thank you very much for the info.